# My .NET Regex.Match is hanging possibly due to backtracking

Tags: c#, .net, regex

my application hangs forever when my regex can't find a match. I'm trying match the section of text below (real numbers have been replaced with letters).

```
JIBBERISHNESS           JABBERISHNESS             JIBBERISHNESS                    
          YEAR                  DOLLARAMT            JABBERISHNESS                  
           A                   $XX,XXX.XX         $X,XXX,XXX                      
           B                    XX,XXX.XX         JIBBERISHNESS              
           C                    XX,XXX.XX           JABBERISHNESS                 
           D                    XX,XXX.XX                                         
           E                    XX,XXX.XX                                         
           F                    XX,XXX.XX                                         
          GG                    XX,XXX.XX                                         
          HH                   XXX,XXX.XX                                         
          KK                   XXX,XXX.XX                                         
      AGE YY                    XX,XXX.XX                                         
  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -           
 0000-HOME OFFIC                  LAST PAGE                        PAGE  3       {
```

i have multiple regexes

```
string YearARegex = @" +A +\$(?<dollarAmtA>(\d{1,3},?)+\.\d\d).*\n";
string YearBRegex = YearARegex + @" +B +(?<dollarAmtB>(\d{1,3},?)+\.\d\d).*\n";
string YearCRegex = YearBRegex + @" +C +(?<dollarAmtC>(\d{1,3},?)+\.\d\d).*\n";
```

that builds on the prior regex for the line before. However, my application hangs on this regex:

```
string AgeXXRegex = YearKKRegex + @" +AGE XX +(?<premiumXX>(\d{1,3},?)+\.\d\d) +\n";
```

I googled the symptoms and my best guess is because of 'catastrophic backtracking'. Can someone confirm this? The target text doesn't seem that big, and the compounding regex I'm using seems specific enough (at least for me the human).

Can someone recommend a solution to prevent the application from hanging?

Comment: Please provide all the source code for us to be able to repro the problem. Right now, `YearKKRegex` is not defined, and this prevents me from testing.

Answer (score 0):

Run your regex matching in a separate thread with timeout:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
int timeOut = 500; // 500 ms

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
  return YearARegex + @" +B +(?<dollarAmtB>(\d{1,3},?)+\.\d\d).*\n"; 
}, token);

if (!task.Wait(timeOut, token))
    Console.WriteLine("The Task timed out!");
```

The result of the task execution will be in task.Result property.
Additionally I would try to combine more optimized regex, at least make usage of

```
^   Start of line
$   End of line
```